# Return blank if the field in HTML FORM is "01/01/1900" with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a HTML FORM that populates a Database in SQL Server where I noticed if the input is blank this field is filling with 01/01/1900

I would like to fill if the input is blank or the literal value "01/01/1900" to get the value blank;

I can not do this if the field required;

```
    <input placeholder="Birthday" class="textbox-n" type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" name="birthday" id="birthday">
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the field 'nullable'?

Comment: yes, the field in database is nullable

Comment: I had an issue with this a couple of days ago. You have to check if the value of the date is null. In that case, you give it a value of  ' '. Null dates happen to be '0' to JS, and '0' becomes '01/01/1900'.